# Setting the language in my app

Tags: android, xml, localization, preferences

**Hello everybody!!! So I try to implement change languages in my application. I do this as follows:**
array.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="Language">
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Ukraine</item>
        <item>French</item>
        <item>Spanish</item>
        <item>Italian</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="languageAlias">
        <item>"en_US"</item>
        <item>"uk_UA"</item>
        <item>"fr"</item>
        <item>"es"</item>
        <item>"it"</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and i have nessesary value -en,-fr, -es with my string value...
And i have SettingsActivity, SettingsFragment.
It's fragmnet:

```
    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Log.i("SettingsFragment", "key = " + key);

        if (key.equals("list_preference")) {
            Log.i("SettingsFragment", "key = "+ key);
            setLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), key);
            restartActivity();
        }
    }

    private void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
        String localeStr = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getString(languageToLoad, "");
        if(localeStr.equals("en_US")){
                Log.i("setLanguage", "en");
                Locale locale = new Locale(localeStr);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            } else
            if(localeStr.equals("uk_UA")){
                Log.i("setLanguage", "uk");
                Locale locale = new Locale(localeStr);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
    }

    private void restartActivity() {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        getActivity().finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

PreferenceScreen inside res/xml/setting.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="PreferenceCategory">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox_preference"
        android:title="CheckBoxPreference.title"
        android:summary="CheckBoxPreference.summary" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="PreferenceCategoryList">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="list_preference"
        android:title="PreferenceCategoryList.title"
        android:summary="PreferenceCategoryList.summary"
        android:entries="@array/Language"
        android:entryValues="@array/languageAlias"
        android:dialogTitle="PreferenceCategoryList.dialogTitle" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

But when I select a language from the list, it works, but when you restart the app and it will not has been selected.
Also wanted to ask whether the right way to implement I choose? Possibility there a better way? More current or correct? Please Share Useful links associated with this topic.

**Thank you for your attention, I'm sorry if poorly expressed his description of the problem.**

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the built in lcoale changing ability of the OS?

Comment: Sry, but i dont understood, your question

Comment: Changing languages, and changing all the strings of your app, is built into the OS.  All you need to do is provide appropriate strings.xml files, and if the user changes their device language all the apps will switch strings to that language.  Why not just use this functionality rather than rewrite it on your own?

Comment: Clearly you are clearly explained, but I would like the opportunity to implement changes to the program itself, and to restart the application after it remained, and what was set in the program, which is not the default (as in my case).